# MutationObserver resulting in TypeError: Parameter 1 is not of type Node

Tags: javascript, typeerror, nodes, e-commerce, mutation-observers

#### ERROR

Need help figuring out why MutationObserver API isn't working for me. I don't understand why I am receiving this error code when document.querySelectorAll('.cart__item') should return a NodeList.

I currently I have one list item (.cart__item) hard coded into the HTML and it still gives me the error. Below is the condensed version of the code to just display the MutationObserver I added.

*Full Project:* https://codepen.io/jdubtheegreat/pen/oNygMOM?editors=1010

```
// Add To Cart / Update Cart Menu
let cartListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.cart__item');
let options = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};
let observer = new MutationObserver(listUpdate);

function listUpdate(mutations) {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
            console.log('Mutation Detected: A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
    }
}

const addToCart = document.querySelector('.add-to-cart button');
addToCart.addEventListener('click', function () {

    

    observer.observe(cartListItems, options);
});
```

Ultimately the goal is to watch the cart menu for changes and then add the ability to remove the items and update the notification icon.

I am open to different ideas/solutions to achieving this task. Just want to learn how to execute this properly.

#### Solution

**EDIT:** *Figured out why my code wasn't running properly. It's because I had the MutationObserver observing the wrong class. Instead of observing the list item (li) elements I had to observe the parent container with the unordered list (ul). Now it recognizes items updated to the cart.*